# NIO Files.createTempDirectory on Windows causes exception

Tags: java, nio

I've got a bit of code that's supposed to create a temporary directory in the temporary file location on the system:

```
try {
            Path tempdir = Files.createTempDirectory("tempmm");
            tempdir.toFile().deleteOnExit();
            tempFilename = format("%s/%s.zip", tempdir, meetId);

            // Handle windows
            //tempFilename = tempFilename.replace("\\", "/");

            uri = URI.create("jar:file:" + tempFilename);

            System.out.println("temp file uri = " + uri.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.severe(format("Unable to create temporary directory: %s", e.toString()));
    }
```

and

```
try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, new HashMap<String, String>() {{ put("create", "true"); }})) {

            Path externalMMFile = Paths.get(filePath);
            Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath(externalMMFile.getFileName().toString());

            // copy Meet Manager Database file into the zip file
            Files.copy(externalMMFile,pathInZipfile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.severe("Unable to create zip upload file!");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            return false;
 }
```

This is the exception that's occuring:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Ill
egal character in opaque part at index 11: jar:file:C:\DOCUME~1\David\LOCALS~1\T
emp\tempmm6286934818003944424/107.zip
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Ill
egal character in opaque part at index 11: jar:file:C:\DOCUME~1\David\LOCALS~1\T
emp\tempmm6286934818003944424/107.zip
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this in a platform-independent way?

Answer (score 1):

I identified the problem. A URI like this:

```
jar:file:C:/temp/yourmum.zip
```

won't work on Windows. It should be:

```
jar:file:/C:/temp/yourmum.zip
```

So I did this:

```
try {
        Path tempdir = Files.createTempDirectory("tempmm");
        tempdir.toFile().deleteOnExit();
        tempFilename = format("%s" + File.separator + "%s.zip", tempdir, meetId);

        if (tempFilename.contains(":\\")) {
            tempFilename = "/" + tempFilename;
        }

        // Handle windows
        tempFilename = tempFilename.replace("\\", "/");

        System.out.println("tempFilename = " + tempFilename);

        uri = URI.create("jar:file:" + tempFilename);

        System.out.println("temp file uri = " + uri.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.severe(format("Unable to create temporary directory: %s", e.toString()));
    }
```

I don't know if this is the best solution, but it worked for me. The tild's weren't all an issue, it was the separators.